# GTK drawing area is not realized

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

In my application I am using a `Gtk::DrawingArea` like this:

```
Window win;
DrawingArea area;
Box box(ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
area.signal_realize().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(&on_video_area_realize));
box.pack_start(myWidgets, true, true);
box.pack_start(area, false, false);
win.add(box);
win.show_all();
```

The problem is, the function `on_video_area_realize` is not being called and if I query the status of the DrawingArea with `area.get_realized()`, it is `false`, so it has not been realized yet.

I do not understand why it has not been realized? As far as I understand, a widget is realized when it is added to a window - which, as far as I think, I am doing already.

Comment: [The `realize` signal has to do with GDK window creation, which not all widgets have.](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-realize) What are you trying to do?

Comment: Im trying to use the DrawingArea to display gstreamer video data, like it is shown in this example:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-gstvideooverlay.html#gst-video-overlay-set-window-handle under "GstVideoOverlay and Gtk+"

Comment: I am using a temporary fix now: Manually realizong the DrawingArea by calling the c function `gtk_widget_realize` on it, which is actually a protected member in gtkmm so I cant use it there....

Comment: Also is this GTK+ 2 or GTK+ 3?

Comment: It is Gtk+ 3, im using gtkmm

Comment: Why can't you wait for the draw event and do something then instead?

Comment: @oldtechaa from what I can tell, GStreamer doesn't work that way. I'm not sure what the answer is; a GStreamer expert will have to answer. Sorry.

Comment: I dont think GStreamer is the cause of this problem, because it is just using the `Gdk::Window` from the `Gtk::DrawingArea` to display its output and in no way interacts with Gtk itself, which is in turn responsible for realizing the `DrawingArea`. Also, I still use the fix of just using the Gtk+ function `gtk_widget_realize`, like its done in the code sample from GStreamer also, but this function is not accesible in C++ Gtkmm. It solves the problem, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The realize signal happens when the window (and its children) is `show`ed. The following code (I tested this with Gtkmm 3.24.20):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>

void on_video_area_realize()
{
    std::cout << "Video drawing area realized!" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Gtkmm version : " << gtk_get_major_version() << "."
                                    << gtk_get_minor_version() << "."
                                    << gtk_get_micro_version() << std::endl;

    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.examples.base");
  
    Gtk::Window window;
    Gtk::Box layout{Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL};
    Gtk::Label label{"Example"};
    
    std::cout << "Checkpoint 1" << std::endl;
    
    Gtk::DrawingArea area;

    std::cout << "Checkpoint 2" << std::endl;

    area.signal_realize().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(&on_video_area_realize));
    
    std::cout << "Checkpoint 3" << std::endl;

    layout.pack_start(label, true, true);
    layout.pack_start(area, false, false);
    
    std::cout << "Checkpoint 4" << std::endl;

    window.add(layout);
    window.show_all();
    
    std::cout << "Checkpoint 5" << std::endl;
  
    return app->run(window);
}
```

Yields the following output:

```
Gtkmm version : 3.24.20
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 2
Checkpoint 3
Checkpoint 4
Video drawing area realized!
Checkpoint 5
```

From this, we can see that the drawing area *is* realized, but not when added to the window.